# Problemas categoria WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou cuidando de um site de notícias em WordPress e percebi que quando é selecionado mais de uma categoria por matéria da o seguinte conflito:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pela URL eu estou na página da categoria Lifestyle só que ele retorna as matéria de Saúde/Beleza. Essas matérias estão marcadas como categoria :Lifestyle, Saúde/Beleza. Esse é o código da página das categorias

```
get_header(); ?>
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
<?php
        if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
<?php
$args = array(
    'category_name' => $slug
);
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category');
if( !empty($terms) ) :
    $term = array_pop($terms);
    $cor = get_field('cor', $term );
    $slug = $term->slug;
endif;
?>

<h1 style="color:<?php echo $cor; ?>" class="page-title tac"><?php echo $term->name; ?></h1>



            </header><!-- .page-header -->

<!-- Notícia em destaque -->            
<!-- Notícia sozinha na DIV -->
            <?php

                                    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category');
                                    if( !empty($terms) ) :
                                        $term = array_pop($terms);
                                        $slug = $term->slug;
                                    endif;

                            // The Query
                            $args = array(
                                'post_type' => 'post',
                                'posts_per_page' => 2,
                                'category_name' => $slug
                            );
                            $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                            if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
                                $cols = 0;
                                $ids = array();
                                while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                                $ids[] = get_the_ID();
                                $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category');
                                    if( !empty($terms) ) :
                                        $term = array_pop($terms);
                                        $cor = get_field('cor', $term );
                                    endif;

                                    ?>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
        <h1 class="title-main" style="color:<?php echo $cor; ?>">
            <?php echo get_field('titulo_chamada'); ?>
        </h1>
    </a>

    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="img-destaque img-responsive" style="background-image: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>); ">
            <div class="tag-category branco" style="background-color: <?php echo $cor; ?>">
                <?php echo $term->name; ?>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </a>
     <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

</div>
                                    <?php

                                endwhile;
                                /* Restore original Post Data */
                                wp_reset_postdata();
                endif;
            ?>
                        <!-- PUBLICIDADE -->
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 img-responsive mw100pc" style="float: right;">
                            <?php echo do_shortcode("[pro_ad_display_adzone id=1043]"); ?>
                        </div>

<!-- Quatro primeiras notícias -->
<div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="row">
        <?php

            $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category');
                            if( !empty($terms) ) :
                                $term = array_pop($terms);
                                $slug = $term->slug;
                            endif;
                            // The Query
                            $args = array(
                                'post_type' => 'post',
                                'post__not_in' => $ids,
                                'posts_per_page' => 4,
                                'category_name' => $slug,
                                ‘showposts’ => 1, 
                                ‘paged’=>$paged
                            );
                            $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                            if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
                                $cols = 0;
                                while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                                $ids[] = get_the_ID();
                                $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category');
                                    if( !empty($terms) ) :
                                        $term = array_pop($terms);
                                        $cor = get_field('cor', $term );
                                    endif;

                                    ?>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="height: 620px;">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                    <h1 class="title-main" style="color:<?php echo $cor; ?>">
                        <?php echo get_field('titulo_chamada'); ?>
                    </h1>
                </a>

                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                    <div class="img-destaque" style="background-image: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>); ">
                        <div class="tag-category branco" style="background-color: <?php echo $cor; ?>">
                            <?php echo $term->name; ?>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </a>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>             

            </div>
            <?php                   
                endwhile;       
                    /* Restore original Post Data */
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                endif;
            ?>
     </div>
</div>

<!-- Resto das noticias da categoria -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="slide-noticias">
            <?php

            $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category');
                                    if( !empty($terms) ) :
                                        $term = array_pop($terms);
                                        $slug = $term->slug;
                                    endif;
                            // The Query
                            $args = array(
                                'post_type' => 'post',
                                'post__not_in' => $ids,
                                'posts_per_page' => 4,
                                'category_name' => $slug,
                                ‘showposts’ => 1, 
                                ‘paged’=>$paged
                            );
                            $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                            if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
                                $cols = 0;
                                while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                                $ids[] = get_the_ID();
                                $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category');
                                    if( !empty($terms) ) :
                                        $term = array_pop($terms);
                                        $cor = get_field('cor', $term );
                                    endif;

                                    ?>
                                    <div class="col-md-3" style="height: 620px;"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <h1 class="title-main" style="color:<?php echo $cor; ?>"><?php echo get_field('titulo_chamada'); ?></h1></a>
                                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <div class="img-destaque" style="background-image: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>); ">



                                        <div class="tag-category branco" style="background-color: <?php echo $cor; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></div> 
                                        </div>
                                        </a>
                                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>             

                                    </div>
                                    <?php

                                endwhile;


                                /* Restore original Post Data */
                                wp_reset_postdata();
                endif;
            ?> 
            </div>
        </div>

            <!-- Paginação -->

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <br />
            <br />          

            <!--BANNER-->
                 <div class="col-xs-12 img-responsive" id="closer">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode("[pro_ad_display_adzone id='1049' class='banner-categoria']"); ?>
             <a hrfe="#" class="modal-close hidden-xs" onclick="document.getElementById('closer').style.display='none'"></a>
                </div>  <!-- /.publicidade -->

                        <div class="clear"></div>


<!-- PROVISÓRIO -->

<hr>

                        <?php
                                // The Query
                                $args = array(
                                    'post_type' => 'post',
                                    'category_name' => $term->slug,
                                    'post__not_in' => $ids,
                                    'posts_per_page' => 10
                                );
                                $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                                if ( $query->have_posts() ) :

                                    $colun = 1;
                                        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                                        $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category');
                                        if( !empty($terms) ) :
                                            $term = array_pop($terms);
                                            $cor = get_field('cor', $term );
                                        endif;
                                        ?>
                                            <?php if($colun == 1 or $colun == 6) : ?><div class="col-md-6"><?php endif; ?>
                                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" style="color:<?php echo $cor; ?>"><h1 class="title-resume"><?php echo get_field('titulo_chamada'); ?></h1></a>
                                            <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
                                            <hr>
                                            <?php if($colun == 5 or $colun == 10) : ?></div><?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php

                                        $colun++;

                                    endwhile;
                                    /* Restore original Post Data */
                                    wp_reset_postdata();
                                endif;
                            ?>
<?php endif; ?> <!-- DEVE PERMANECER NA PÁGINA -->

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

<?php
get_footer();
?>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://d335luupugsy2.cloudfront.net/js/loader-scripts/7270b716-ffb6-4f76-8de0-9f09b12a4159-loader.js"></script>

<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-68151385-5', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

<script>
$('.slide-noticias').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
    // settings: "unslick"
    // instead of a settings object
  ]
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema está aqui:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category');
    if( !empty($terms) ) :
        $term = array_pop($terms);
        $slug = $term->slug;
    endif;
```

`get_the_terms()` traz uma lista das categorias associadas ao post sem nenhuma ordem especial (acho que vem na ordem que foram gravadas no banco), aí em `$term = array_pop($terms)` você dispensa todos os outros termos e fica só com o último. Aí joga esse termo em `category_name => $slug` e refaz a query, não tem como trazer mais de uma categoria assim.

A rigor, e pelo que dá pra ver do layout, todas esses chamadas pra `$query = new WP_Query` são desnecessárias. Só de chamar a página com a URL certa vc já tem os posts corretos pra exibir. As alterações feitas nesse pedaço:

```
// The Query
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post__not_in' => $ids,
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'category_name' => $slug,
    'showposts' => 1, 
    'paged'=>$paged
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Poderiam ser feitas uma vez só, pelo hook [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/), e a página ficaria limpa, rodando apenas a consulta original.

ps.: uma solução **terrível, horrível e não recomendada** pra ter os posts aparecendo corretamente seria trocar:

```
$term = array_pop($terms);
$slug = $term->slug;
```

por

```
$term_ids = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'term_id' );
```

e
`'category_name' => $slug,` por `'category__in' => $term_ids`

Isso vai fazer os posts aparecerem, mas você continua fazendo 3 ou 4 vezes mais consultas ao banco ($$$) do que o necessário.

Comment: A sua solução funcionou em partes, ele começou a retornar as matérias mas ele trouxe todas as matérias relacionadas a Lifestyle. Por exemplo: em Moda ele está trazendo Saúde/Beleza, Lifestyle, em Saúde/Beleza ele traz Moda, Lifestyle sendo que eu quero que ele traga só a categoria escolhida. E na página gastronomia persiste igual antes. :/

Comment: Em Moda ele está trazendo posts que *não* tem a categoria moda?

Comment: Acabei de ver que tinha sobrescrito a variavel $terms no meu exemplo. Mudei ali pra $term_ids, veja se muda algo.

Comment: Troquei a variavel e não alterou nada. Em relação a primeira pergunta, está retornando todos os posts (lifestyle, moda, saude/beleza) sendo que era pra retornar apenas moda ou apenas saude/beleza, dependendo da página que o cara selecionou. Veja: http://piradigital.com.br/categoria/moda

Comment: O primeiro post (Coluna Ergolife:) que esta marcado como saude e beleza, tb está como lifestyle (pela URL). Ele não tem a categoria moda?

Comment: Não os únicos posts que tem moda são: "Quatro tendências dos anos 90 que voltaram com tudo!" e "Dress Code Fashion Italy traz dicas de moda e comportamento"

Comment: Tem ideia do que possa ser?

Answer (score -1):

Não entendi qual conflito da.

No WordPress, quando vc seleciona diversas categorias em um post, ele coloca na URL amigável do post a primeira categoria q vc selecionou.

E o post sempre aparece nas categorias selecionadas.

O código não tem nada de errado, tá pegando os posts da categoria selecionada, como esse post tá nas duas categorias, logo, vai exibir nessa categoria também.

Comment: Explicando fica meio confuso...entre no site piradigital.com.br, vai na categoria cultura ou em lifestyle. Lifestyle vai retornar apenas saúde/beleza e cultura vai retorna só entretenimento

Comment: Ainda não entendi. O que era pra retornar? Existe matérias da categoria Lifestyle que não estão aparecendo, apenas as matérias da Saúde/Beleza?

Comment: Isso só está aparecendo da saúde/beleza....mas tipo se eu entrar na página Lifestyle vai aparecer saúde/beleza, isso q é o problema. Na página Lifestyle era pra aparecer só lifestyle e n saúde e beleza

Comment: Para ficar um pouco mais claro, se você voltar lá no site era para as demais categorias estarem funcionando igual as categorias 'cidade' e 'região'.